# Possible to download a 360 image from Google Streetview in C#?

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-street-view

I know that tools like [this](https://svd360.istreetview.com/) exist but I am yet to find one that does the job in C#. Does a library or open source one exist or at the very least is it possible to make? If it is possible to make can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is [download every separate tile image](http://www.newtonscannon.com/2014/01/26/capturing-spherical-scenes-from-google-streetview/) and [stitch them together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57110458/9819256) into a single image.